# Android ListView how to get click not on item

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have a listview with a padding top. I need to detect when the empty space on top is clicked.

I tried OnClickLister but I cannot use it on ListView. OnItemClickListener works only when I click on a row.

Comment: Add your code of Adapter

Comment: create a header like here and attach a listener to it: https://blograchita.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/listview-with-header-footer-view-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `header` with nothing in it to `listView` and set `onClickListener` for that header

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnTouchListener` and check if the `Y` coordinate of the `MotionEvent` is less than your padding :

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    final int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.listView_padding);
                    if (motionEvent.getY() < padding) {
                        // do stuff here
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Space with a listener attached on it instead of padding. Or add a listener to the parent view and look for that event.